# Interleaving non group shapes into a group

Tags: kineticjs

I'm working on a drawing App which allows users to place symbols on a canvas and then interconnect those symbols.

I've defined a symbol by extending a Kenitic.group and a Connector by extending a kinetic.circle. So I can define a symbol with a red square and then a connector in the middle of that red square. The user can place a number of these symbols and then in connection "Mode" clicking on a symbol's connector starts drawing a line from the connector. Click on a second symbol's connector and that's a connection established.

This works for one connection but when I go back to make a second connection the connector circle is covered by the line (connection) so the hot spot can't be clicked. It would be a better solution if I could place the line (connection) under the circle (connector) once a connection is made.

A kenitic.group is all on one layer. So to interleave the line under the circle I'd have to take the circle out of the group. Then moving the symbol would be a headache as the symbol's connector would not move with the symbol.

I wonder does anybody have any clever solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Just occurred to me to use trigonometry to recalculate the end points of the Lines to be just short of the circles.